# How to get answer only the image on which mouse is, in the text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is  the JS code:

```js
function flag(){ 
    document.getElementById("f1").value = "country1";
    document.getElementById("f1").value = "country2";
}

function clean(){
    document.getElementById("country1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("country2").value = "";
}

HTML code
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flag name</title>
  <script src="flag.js"></script>
  <script src="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\jq\jquery.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="flag.css">
</head>
<body>
  <img src="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flag1.png" id="flag1" onmouseover="flag()" onmouseout="clean()">
  <img src="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flag2.png" id="flag2" onmouseover="flag()" onmouseout="clean()">
  <form action="#" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="Flag1" id="f1">
    <input type="text" name="Flag2" id="f2">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to get the result in separate text box when mouse is hovered over the image of a country flag.

I want only the output on which mouse is present.

Comment: use onblur event and pass event.target

Comment: function flag(){ 
 document.getElementById("f1").value = "country1";
 document.getElementById("f2").value = "country2";
    }

Comment: Vivek Thakur  check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow, i think this could be a more generic solution for you:

```js
function flag(element) {
  document.getElementById(element.getAttribute('data-target')).value = element.id;
}

function clean(element) {
  document.getElementById(element.getAttribute('data-target')).value = ''
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" id="country1" data-target="f1" onMouseOver="flag(this)" onMouseOut="clean(this)">
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" id="country2" data-target="f2" onMouseOver="flag(this)" onMouseOut="clean(this)">
<form action="#" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="Flag1" id="f1">
  <input type="text" name="Flag2" id="f2">
</form>
```

Comment: Thnx, it's very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
      $("#flag1").mouseover(function() {
        $("#f1").val("country1");
      });

        $("#flag1").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#f1").val("");
      });

       $("#flag2").mouseover(function() {
        $("#f2").val("country2");
      });
      
        $("#flag2").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#f2").val("");
      });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flag name</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="images/banner1.png" id="flag1">
  <img src="images/mobile.png" id="flag2">
  <form action="#" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="Flag1" id="f1">
    <input type="text" name="Flag2" id="f2">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you serious right now?Instead of simplifying things, you are complicating them even more..

Answer (score 0):

onMouseOver

```js
function flag(id){ 
 document.getElementById("f1").value = id;
}

function clean(){
    document.getElementById("country1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("country2").value = "";
}
HTML code
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Flag name</title>
 <script src = "flag.js"></script>
 <script src = "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\jq\jquery.3.js"></script>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" text = "text/css" href = "flag.css">
</head> 
<body>
<img onmouseover="flag(this.id))" src = "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flag1.png" id = "flag1" onmouseout = "clean()">
<img onmouseover="flag(this.id))" src = "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flag2.png" id = "flag2" onmouseout = "clean()">
<form action = "#" method = "GET">
 <input type = "text" name = "Flag1" id = "f1">
 <input type = "text" name = "Flag2" id = "f2">
</form>
</body>
</html> onmouseover="bigImg(this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `event` or `this` inside of `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event

1. You can find the textfield by using `document.querySelector()` and set value inside of onmouseover/onmouseout
2. You can get the you target attribute value using `getAttribute()` method.

**DEMO**

```js
function flag(tag) {
  document.querySelector(`[name=${tag.id}]`).value = tag.getAttribute('value');
}

function clean(tag) {
  document.querySelector(`[name=${tag.id}]`).value = '';
}
```

```html
<img src="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flag1.png" value="Country 1" id="flag1" onmouseover="flag(this)" onmouseout="clean(this)">
<img src="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flag2.png" value="Country 2" id="flag2" onmouseover="flag(this)" onmouseout="clean(this)">
<form action="#" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="flag1">
  <input type="text" name="flag2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the structure of you project?

`flag.js` has to be in the same folder that `index.html`. Also link your javascript scripts at the end of the `body`.

And then you have a couple of errors with the `document.getElementById`, you are using the wrong `id`s.

```js
function flag(){ 
 document.getElementById("f1").value = "country1";
 document.getElementById("f2").value = "country2";
}

function clean(){
    document.getElementById("f1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("f2").value = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flag name</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="flag.css">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flag1.png" id="flag1" onmouseover="flag()" onmouseout="clean()">
    <img src="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flag2.png" id="flag2" onmouseover="flag()" onmouseout="clean()">
    <form action="#" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="Flag1" id="f1">
        <input type="text" name="Flag2" id="f2">
    </form>
    <script src="flag.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\jq\jquery.3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use o  onmouseover = "flag()" the parameter this.id like

`<img src="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flag1.png" id="flag1" onmouseover="flag(this.id)" onmouseout = "clean()">`

and after make a if to put the value

`if (parameter == flag'){
   put one flag
}else{
   put the other flag
}`